# How to validate a password allows at least 4 digits and 1 character without special character using regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

How to validate a password allows at least 4 digits and 1 character without special character using regular expression?

Password Valid Format: 1234a or 6778B or 67A89 (Without Special Characters Like @$%^&*/)

Maximum Password Length : 5 Characters Long

Can any one help me how to do this?.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you attempted to implement this yourself? Where exactly are you having problems? At the moment, this post seems to be requesting us to do the work for you... It's just a list of specs.

Comment: Which of the following are valid  1234a 12345 1234#

Answer (score 2):

The pattern you want

- any number of numbers
- then a letter
- any number of numbers
- additional restriction as in all should not be longer than 5 chars

The patter could be this: (using positive lookahead to check the numbers-letter-numbers combination then checking for 5 characters to check length)

```
/^(?=[0-9]*[a-zA-Z][0-9]*$).{5}$/
```

Comment: I do not believe that Javascript supports mode modifiers

Comment: Thanks @RonRosenfeld, I removed the `i`

Answer (score 1):

This regex should work:

```
^(?=(.*?[0-9]){4})(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])[0-9A-Za-z]{5}$
```

Since we are only allowing `[0-9A-Za-z]{5}` symbols in password there is no need to check for special characters here.

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/mB6sS5

**Explanation:**

- `(?=(.*?[0-9]){4})` - Lookahead to check for presence of at least 4 numbers
- `(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])` - Lookahead to check for presence at least 1 letter
- `[0-9A-Za-z]{5}` Only allows symbols in character class with max length=5

Comment: I don't think that's correct. The first lookahead will not check if there are at lest 4 numbers but will only accept 4 numbers following each other. So 67A89 would not match for example

Comment: @fejese: You probably didn't understand the regex or didn't check the linked demo. If you do check linked demo it is indeed matching `67A89` as valid.

Comment: @ahalya, my bad, I missed a parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

```
^[0-9]{4}[A-Za-z]{1}$
```

This will let you enter four numbers (0-9) and 1 letter (a-z and A-Z) example 1234a.... hope this is the answer you were looking for.

Comment: that will let you enter 4 didgets and 1 letter, that is what you asked for, that is what I gave, thanks for the vote down

Comment: Note that I am not the user asking the question.

Comment: ohh I see that now.. my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Below is the javascript code for doing the checking you need

```
var regex =^(?=(.*?[0-9]){4})(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])[0-9A-Za-z]{5}$; 
var input = "1234B"; 
if(regex.test(input)) {
    alert(matches[match]);
} else 
{
  alert("No matches found!");
}
```

Comment: Same issue with this as with @anubhava's: not accepting passwords like 67A89

Comment: @ahalya Hai ahalya if my answer helps you please accept it.